# OnClick function one being fired from masterpage file

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have put below code in a .aspx file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/uoa-bs.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SubjectListing" 
Title="Course outlines - Browse outlines by subject | The University of Auckland Business School"
 Codebehind="SubjectListing.aspx.cs" %>
```

and uoa-bs.master is the file in which i have included the script as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common_js.comp.js"></script>
```

The script has the onClick function but when i click it says that "The function not found". Looks like my script is not being fired.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/uoa-bs.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SubjectListing" 
Title="Course outlines - Browse outlines by subject | The University of Auckland Business School"
 Codebehind="SubjectListing.aspx.cs" %>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common_js.comp.js"></script>

Comment: 1st one is my coding from asp flle and 2nd is from master file.

Comment: Show the code where you call the JavaScript function. and, is the path given in src="js/common_js.comp.js" correct?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Path was correct but it did not have / in front. i updated it to  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common_js.comp.js"></script> and it works now. Thaks

Comment: Show the code where you call the JS function. And, try calling a different function within the same file.